# Jest / Ts-Jest / Babel : Debug Failure. False expression: Output generation failed

Tags: node.js, typescript, babeljs, jestjs

With TypeScript 2.8, we have now the possiblity to generate .d.ts only from source files. So my tsconfig.json becomes :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["ES6","ES2017","ESNext"],
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "declarationDir": "./lib"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "strict": true
}
```

The problem is the build is broken with that (https://travis-ci.org/jy95/mediaScan/jobs/359573738).
My repo : https://github.com/jy95/mediaScan/tree/prettier

Any ideas how to fix it ?

My jest.config.js :

```
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
    verbose: true,
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
        "ts",
        "tsx",
        "js"
    ],
    "transform": {
        "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "testMatch": [
        "<rootDir>/__tests__/**/*.(ts|tsx|js)"
    ],
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": ["<rootDir>/node_modules/", "<rootDir>/__tests__/__helpers__/"],
    "collectCoverage": true
};
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've experienced similar issue when was switching `jest` to process `.js` files with `ts-jest` instead of `babel-jest`.

Error happens (according to stacktrace) at `getConstructorDefinedThisAssignmentTypes` in `typescript.js`. And is most likely caused by incorrect or missing types. Add some breakpoints or log types there/declarations to see what exactly is failing.

You can try to upgrade `typescript` to the latest version, it might give more valuable error message, and try to `tsc --noEmit` to see if there are some loose ends with your types.

Also sometimes `npx jest --clearCache` helps